# Am I correct in interpreting the integral of this delta-function graph?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have $f(x)$ defined as $\delta(x)-\delta(x-\frac{1}{2})$ $\forall x\in(-\frac{1}{6},\frac{3}{4})$. Outside this boundary it is periodically repeating.

From the definition of the $\delta$-function, when $x=\frac{1}{2}$, $f(x)=-1$ and when $x=0$, $f(x)=1$.

Visually, I interpret this as an upward blip to $\infty$ at $x=0$ and a downward blip to $-\infty$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. This repeats as we go along the x-axis.

Is this a correct interpretation?

If so, I go to my next question.

From this it can be seen that $$\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=1$$ because between the points $x=-1$ and $x=1$ we have 3 upward blips at $x=-1,0,1$ and 2 downward blips at $x=-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}$. Since the area of each upward blip is 1 and the area of each downward blip is -1 we have the total area and hence the integral to be $3-2=1$.

However, if I split the integral into four parts my answer seems to be different: $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx+\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x)dx.$$

This would imply that for the first integral, the upward blip at $-1$ and the downward blip and $-\frac{1}{2}$ will cancel, making the integral zero. The same would then occur for all subsequent integrals. For example, for the second integral the downward blip at $-\frac{1}{2}$ and the upward blip at $0$ will cancel, rendering the integral zero.

Obviously I have misunderstanding somewhere, since this doesn't make sense. Please don't explicitly answer my question, just give me hints as to where I am going wrong or where I have a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the dirac delta function $\delta(x)$ is undefined at $x=0$, you can think of it as being 'infinite' there, but this isn't strictly true. Thus $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Your intuition in terms of 'blips' is correct however.

For your second question, note that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x)dx=1,$$
but
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}\delta(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

One way to think of this is to view $\delta(x)$ as the limit of a series of Gaussians, [as on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). In that case if you are integrating to $0$ you will only have half of the area of the Gaussian.

Comment: Ah interesting! So I will have a total area between -1 and 1 as $(\frac{1}{2}+1+\frac{1}{2})+(-1)+(-1)=2-2=0$ ??

Comment: I'm a bit unsure how you are defined $f$, when you say 'it is repeating outside of the boundary $(-\frac{1}{6},\frac{3}{4})$'. Do you mean it is an upward blip at every integer and a downwards blip at every half integer? In that case we can look at $f$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ as $f=\delta(x-(-1))-\delta(x-(-1/2)+\delta(x-0)-\delta(x-1/2)+\delta(x-1)$, and so the integral from $-1$ to $1$ will be $1/2-1+1-1+1/2=2$.